# Next iteration in `each` loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a collection:

```
@monday = HomeTask.where(:class_room => current_user.class_room, :day => 'Понеділок').order(created_at: :desc)
```

The `@monday` variable contains data from the database. In view, I show all dates from the collection:

```
<% @monday.each_with_index do |mnd, i| %>
  <% if mnd.data == mnd.data[i + 1] %>
    <%= link_to 'nice' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to 'ohhh...' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Within `if` body, I want to refer to the next element. But it does not work. In C++, to refer to the next element in the first iteration, it would be coded like this:

```
if(array[i] == array[i+1])
```

How do I use `each` in Ruby?

Comment: For consistency try and steer towards using the `x: :y` notation for hash options. This one line of code uses both the new style and the old style with "fat arrow" `=>`.

Comment: `<% if mnd.data == mnd.data[i + 2] %>` - yep try? but don`t work

Comment: In your C code you do `i + 1` but in Ruby you do `i + 2`. Why the difference? Remember you can't do `i + 1` if `i == @monday.length` because that'll walk off the end of the array.

Comment: tadman => I don`t understand, pls explain

Comment: The equivalent of your C example would be `@monday.each_with_index { |mnd, i| mnd == @monday[i + 1] }` ... Remember that the each iterator yields only one element at a time, but you still have access to the named array. Of course, other answers here point to a more Ruby-ish approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to iterate an array and have access to more than one item in each iteration you can use [each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons)

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
arr.each_cons(2){|a,b| 
   puts "#{a} : #{b}"
}
# 1 : 2
# 2 : 3
# 3 : 4
# 4 : 5
# 5 : 6
# 6 : 7
# 7 : 8
```

Using each_cons you can easily compare two (or more) consecutive items of an array.

Comment: `<% @monday.each_cons(2) do |mnd, i| %>
  <% if mnd.data == i.data] %>
   ` -  this is my final and working code, ty community

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

enum = arr.to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]:each>    
loop { puts "%d : %d" % [enum.next, enum.peek] }
1 : 2
2 : 3
3 : 4
4 : 5
5 : 6
6 : 7
7 : 8
```

See [Kernel#to_enum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-to_enum)<sup>1</sup>, [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-loop), [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Enumerator#peek](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek). `peek` raises a `StopIteration` exception when it is executed after the last element of `arr` has been generated. `loop` handles that exception by breaking out of the loop.

<sup>1. As to why this `Kernel` instance method is documented as an `Object` instance method, please see the second paragraph at the docs for [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

What if you could go with following changes,

```
-  <% if mnd.data == mnd.data[i + 1] %>
+  <% if @monday[i+1] != nil && mnd.data == @monday[i+1].data %>
```

Or simply,

```
-  <% if mnd.data == mnd.data[i + 1] %>
+  <% if mnd.data == @monday[i+1].try(:data) %>
```